# JavaFX how to preserve the state of a tableview

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a `JAVAFX` application. In my application, after clicking a button, it opens one window which has a `TableView` in it with one `Apply` and `Save` button. When clicking on the `Apply` button, it will preserve the current state of the `TableView` (in case we add/remove the table rows and click apply and reopen the table the previously updated `TableView` should be shown). The `Save` button is to save the table records to a database. Suppose there are two rows (coming from the database) in the table and if I add a 3rd row and click `Apply` my `TableView` window will be closed. And If I reopen the table the third row is not present.

How do I preserve that previously added third row, without inserting it into the database?

Comment: So, when you open the window, items coming from a DB - this is the initial state of your table. Then you can press Save or Apply: Save will store items into the DB, Apply will store items in the DB and close the window. So the difference between the two buttons is just Apply closes the window also. Do I understand it well? Just because, on the next open, items will come from the DB - as it is the initial state - and the items were stored in the DB on the previous window, therefore I don't understand the question. Or you just have a typo: "The third record will NOT be stored in DB ... "?

Comment: only SAVE button will store the table data in DB. APPLY button will not save table data in DB. With APPLY button I just want to save the current state of the Table. E.g. when I open the tableview for the first time. And if there are two records which are coming from DB. Now if I add one more row/record in the table and if I click APPLY button nothing will be inserted in DB but the current state of the table (Having three rows) should be preserved and when next time I open the table three rows should shown (first two from DB) and third one is which I added

Comment: So, the third one is only stored in memory? Sounds like you need to create a property to get ahold of this data source for the `TableView`, check if a row doesn't exist in the database and if so, stored it as an object in your application. What have you tried so far? Do you have some sample code of how the `TableView` is and how you populate it with data?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to store the items of the `TableView` (or optionally just the list of the added items of the `TableView`) as a member in the class that opens the window.

**I have created an example:**

The application `TableViewSample` can be used to open a second window. This application stores an instance of `TablePopUp` which class can show a second modal `Stage`, while maintaining a "buffer" - a list of `Person` (the data model what is displayed on the `TableView`) object, that were added to the `TableView` and were "Applied" but not stored in the database yet.

```
public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    // Stores the state of the TableView and opens the second window
    TablePopUp popUp = new TablePopUp();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        BorderPane root = (BorderPane) scene.getRoot();

        Button button = new Button("Open window");
        button.setOnAction((e) -> popUp.showTable());

        root.setCenter(button);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    class TablePopUp {

        // Stores the Person object which were added and applied but not stored
        // in DB
        ObservableList<Person> bufferAdd = FXCollections.observableArrayList();




        // Simulate the items coming from the DV
        private ObservableList<Person> dataFromDB = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));

        void showTable() {
            // Temporary buffer for the added Persion objects
            ObservableList<Person> tempBuffer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            // Temporary buffer to store persons to be deleted on apply
            ObservableList<Person> bufferRemoveFromBuffer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            // Data what the TableView displays
            ObservableList<Person> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            // Stores the person objects that will be removed from the DB if Save is pressed
            ObservableList<Person> bufferRemoveFromDB = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            // The Table displays elements from the DB + the applied buffer
            tableData.addAll(dataFromDB);
            tableData.addAll(bufferAdd);

            // Create the table
            TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
            table.setItems(tableData);

            Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane());
            final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

            TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
            firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
            firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

            TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
            lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
            lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

            TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
            emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
            emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

            table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

            TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
            addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
            addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
            TextField addLastName = new TextField();
            addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
            addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
            TextField addEmail = new TextField();
            addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
            addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

            // Button to add a new Person
            Button addButton = new Button("Add");
            addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                    Person newPerson = new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName.getText(), addEmail.getText());

                    // Add a new element to the temporary buffer and add it to
                    // the table data also
                    tempBuffer.add(newPerson);
                    tableData.add(newPerson);
                    addFirstName.clear();
                    addLastName.clear();
                    addEmail.clear();
                }
            });


            // Button to remove a Person
            Button removeButton = new Button("Remove");
            removeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                    Person selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                    if(selectedItem != null) {

                        // Remove the item from the list of the displayed persons
                        tableData.remove(selectedItem);

                        // Check the buffers: if one of the buffer contains the selected item, remove it from the buffer
                        if(tempBuffer.contains(selectedItem))
                            tempBuffer.remove(selectedItem);
                        else if(bufferAdd.contains(selectedItem))
                            bufferRemoveFromBuffer.add(selectedItem);
                        else {
                            // The item is not in the buffers -> remove the item from the DB
                            bufferRemoveFromDB.add(selectedItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            HBox hb = new HBox();
            hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton, removeButton);
            hb.setSpacing(3);

            VBox vbox = new VBox();
            vbox.setSpacing(5);
            vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

            BorderPane root = (BorderPane) scene.getRoot();
            root.setCenter(vbox);

            Stage stage = new Stage();

            HBox applySave = new HBox();

            // On Save:
            // Remove all elements from the buffer that were selected to be deleted
            // Remove all elements from the BD that were selected to be deleted
            // Add all the elements from the persistent buffer to the DB
            // Add all the elements from the temporary buffer to the DB
            // Clear both buffers
            Button saveButton = new Button("Save to DB");
            saveButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
                bufferAdd.removeAll(bufferRemoveFromBuffer);
                dataFromDB.removeAll(bufferRemoveFromDB);


                dataFromDB.addAll(bufferAdd);
                dataFromDB.addAll(tempBuffer);

                bufferAdd.clear();
                stage.close();
            });

            // On Apply:
            // Add elements from the temporary buffer to the persistent buffer
            // Remove elements from the buffer
            Button applyButton = new Button("Apply");
            applyButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
                bufferAdd.addAll(tempBuffer);

                bufferAdd.removeAll(bufferRemoveFromBuffer);

                stage.close();
            });

            applySave.getChildren().addAll(saveButton, applyButton);

            root.setBottom(applySave);

            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

The class `TablePopUp` has actually two buffers: a temporary buffer, which is used to stored the added the elements, and a persistent one which is kept between the different window openings. If the "Apply" button is pressed, the temporary buffer is stored in the persistent one. If the "Save" button is pressed, both buffers are stored in the DB then they gets cleared.

In the example the removing is also buffered. On remove it finds out, that the `Person` object that is selected to be removed coming from the database or not. If it coming from the database, it placed to a buffer and it only gets removed from the database, if the save button is pressed. The same workflow is valid for the persons that are added but not placed into the database yet: on remove they only get removed, if the apply button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Could you please advise on remove..As in my case I have both kinds of records in table view..i.e. few records from DB and few records that I have added which are not from DB.

Comment: Updated the answer for you with the removal part.